# Compare values in single column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Harry', 'John', 'Peter', 'Stan', 'Petra'], 'Score': [10, 9, 5, 7, 8]})
```

I can use itertools to get a matrix

```
for a, b in itertools.combinations(df['Score'], 2):
    print (a, b)
```

What is the best what way to return a matrix comparing each value with an x and y index. for instance:

```
      Harry   John   Peter   Stan   Petra
Harry   -       1      5       3       2
John    -1      -      4       2       1
etc....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.subtract.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.subtract.outer(df['Score'], df['Score']),
                  index=df['Name'], 
                  columns=df['Name'])
```

Or `broadcasting`:

```
a = df['Score'].values
df = pd.DataFrame(a[:, None] - a, columns = df['Name'], index=df['Name'])

print (df)
Name   Harry  John  Peter  Stan  Petra
Name                                  
Harry      0     1      5     3      2
John      -1     0      4     2      1
Peter     -5    -4      0    -2     -3
Stan      -3    -2      2     0     -1
Petra     -2    -1      3     1      0
```

Comment: Thanks for your amazing lightning fast answers! @jezrael